# looping and transposing under a variable

Tags: excel, vba

i have time steps N=x number in x columns, i am trying to loop each column and transpose the numbers in there to specific rows(in the image). i have tried a lot nothing is working. here is my code

```
for i = 0 to N-1 

cells(12,i + 9).Value = cells(N + 7 - i, N + 7).Value 

Next i
```

[image]

**Desired Output**

[image]

Comment: i need to put the numbers in each column to the different rows (payoff) last column goes under the first payoff. and so on, i need to be able to do that wht ever N stands for

Comment: You need to add a screeshot of what you expect for results, given the input you already show.

Comment: done i added what i need , it can be more thank just 4 columns it is N columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that seems to work and should work for `N` columns of data:

I suggest, in your real code, that you have the source data and the results on two different worksheets, as finding the table may be difficult if the data and results overlap.

Note that the "work" is done in VBA arrays, as this is usually much faster than multiple worksheet read/writes.

```
Sub due()
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim rRes As Range, lastCol As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long

    'Assumes, per your code and screenshot, that data starts in H12
    Const firstCol As Long = 8, firstRow As Long = 12

'Worksheet with data
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet5")

'Range with data
'Assumes, per your code and screenshot, that data starts in H12
With wsSrc
    lastCol = .Cells(firstRow, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, lastCol).End(xlUp).Row

    'read the data into an array for processing
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(firstRow, firstCol), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
End With

'create results array
'will have three rows for each column of source data
' and one column for all of the rows of source data

ReDim vRes(1 To UBound(vSrc, 2) * 3, 0 To UBound(vSrc, 1))

'Populate it with the data
'First column is the row headers
For I = 1 To UBound(vRes, 1) Step 3
    vRes(I, 0) = "Possible Price of Assets"
    vRes(I + 1, 0) = "Payoffs"
Next I

'populate the columns
I = 1
J = UBound(vSrc, 1)
Do
    For K = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
        vRes(I, K) = vSrc(K, J)
    Next K
    J = J - 1
    I = I + 3
Loop Until I > UBound(vRes, 1)

With wsSrc
    Set rRes = .Cells(lastRow + 2, 1).Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2) + 1)
    With rRes
        .Clear
        .Value = vRes
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: thank you that works great, i am going through it line by line to understand it, it would be great also if you you can share any link that will teach me how to write as you do, i did not know before how to set up such code due to lack of knowledge of such type of code. or at least a point of start for me.Thank you.